# incrementing shell variable.. what's wrong?

Tags: shell

I want to print Hey %d five times using shell script.

```
 #/bin/csh
 set i=0
 while ($i < 5)
 echo "i=$i"
 echo "Hey $i"
 set i=$i+1
 end
```

It gives me 
while: Badly formed number.

I'm sure the problem is in the incrementing line because if I remove the line, it prints Hey 0 repeatedly.

Comment: Instead of set. Try:  @ i = $i +1

Comment: Variables whose values are integer use a slightly different set command. The commercial-at sign is used instead of "set" to indicate "assignment". Otherwise, the Cshell would use a character string "123" instead of the integer 123.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `expr`:

```
 #/bin/csh
 set i=0
 while ($i < 5)
    echo "Hey $i"
    set i = `expr $i + 1`
 end
```

Comment: Oh, thanks so much! (while following your answer, I also learned space around + is also needed)

Comment: If it worked out for you can you mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.

Comment: changing #!/bin/csh to #!/bin/sh gives me an error below.  
`line 7: syntax error: unexpected end of file`  
How should it be changed for sh(not csh)?

Comment: `sh` is different syntax than csh. In `sh` there is no `set` and no spaces around `=` either.

Comment: Wow, so it becomes 
    `#!/bin/sh
    i=3
    while test $i -lt 5; do  
    echo "Hey $i" i=`expr $i + 1` 
    done